# How to execute prepared statement in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, prepared-statement

I have the following statement that I can execute in MySQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;

SELECT
 GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT'MAX(IF(Name = ''', Name, ''', Name, NULL)) AS `', Name, '`') INTO @sql
from Contact_Types;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT c.First_Name, ', @sql, ' from Contacts c
left join Contacts_Contact_Types cct
  on c.Contact_Id = cct.Contact_Id
left join Contact_Types ct
  on cct.Contact_Type_Id = ct.Contact_Type_Id
group by c.Contact_Id');

PREPARE statement FROM @sql;
EXECUTE statement;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;
```

This prepared statement allows me to dynamically retrieve "contact types" associated with a contact. How can I execute this prepared statement in CodeIgniter and retrieve the results? I can't find any mention of this in the CI documentation.

I receive a SQL syntax error when attempting to execute the following:

```
$this->db->query("PREPARE statement FROM @sql; EXECUTE statement; DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;");
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: Have you tried using the CI query function ? `$this->db->query("SELECT .. ");`

Comment: @DinRevah Yes, I have tried that with no luck. For example, I receive a SQL syntax error using `$this->db->query("PREPARE statement FROM @sql; EXECUTE statement; DEALLOCATE PREPARE statement;");` Thanks for the reply.

Comment: why don't you just use the Codeigniter query builder for queries?

Comment: @DinRevah I'm not sure what you are referring to. I typically use Active Record for queries though. Active Record CodeIgniter documentation makes no mention of executing prepared statements either.